# Read_csv from URL into Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests

Hi I am unable to read CSV file from the URL by using

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data_url = 'https://data.baltimorecity.gov/Financial/Real-Property-Taxes/27w9-urtv.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_url)
df.head()
```

I got an error: "not acceptable"

I also tried different codes importing "requests" but none of them worked. How do I fix this?

Comment: apparently that url is not linked to a csv

Comment: There is no csv file in this URL. Please recheck your URL by loading the URL in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Your URL wasnt correct. This should work:

```
import pandas as pd

data_url = 'https://data.baltimorecity.gov/resource/27w9-urtv.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(data_url)
df.head()
```

Comment: Hi, it has loaded only 1000 rows while the dataset has 238k rows. I checked it while I tried to clean the data